# draw shape in map and save to server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am new to ArcGIS JavaScript API. I want to draw a polygon in map (with javascript in the *ArcGIS* web map) and then edit data for that polygon and then save in a existing layer in ArcGIS Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First you need to publish your polygon layer to ArcGIS Server or [ArcGIS Online](https://www.arcgis.com/home/index.html), in order to get the polygon into a web map.
- Then add that polygon layer to a web map as a [feature layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html).
- Now you can add the [Edit toolbar](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/edit-amd.html), which will allow you to create, update and delete polygon features.

There is a sample [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ed_simpletoolbar.html) which shows you how to edit a feature layer - you can test it in the [sandbox](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=ed_simpletoolbar).

Comment: Or they could start by reading the docs as all the rest of us did when starting coding.

Comment: in step 1, i have created a service definition file (sd file) in arcmap and add publish to arcgis server. the map now showed in web browser, in this step, i want to draw new shape/polygon in map and then the new shape/polygon with data must be saved to original map. when i refresh the browser, the new shap must be show. i didnt find any code and i don't khnow how your code working.